# Ocultar elementos unicos con Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

```js
$(function(){

$('button').on('click',function(){

var s = $('.contenedor p');

if ($(this).text() === 'Ocultar'){
    $(this).text('Mostrar');
    s.fadeOut();    
} else {
    $(this).text('Ocultar');
    s.fadeIn();
}

});
  });
```

```css
.contenedor{
background: #EDEDED; height: 300px; width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<section>
<button>Ocultar</button>
</section>
<div class="contenedor">
    <p>tortuga</p>
</div>
    </div>
<br>
<div class="container">
 <section>
<button>Ocultar</button>
</section>  
<div class="contenedor">
    <p>gato</p>
</div>
    </div>
<br>
<div class="container">
<section>
<button>Ocultar</button>
</section>
<div class="contenedor">
    <p>loro</p>
</div>
    </div>
<br>
<div class="container">
<section>
<button>Ocultar</button>
</section>
<div class="contenedor">
    <p>pato</p>
</div>
    </div>
```

Hola a todos que estén leyendo esto, tengo este código de prueba, en el cual muestra botones y 4 divs que contienen un parrafo. Mi problema es el siguiente, espero me puedan ayudar: No logro hacer que un texto en particular se oculte. Cuando le das en ocultar, se ocultan todos los elementos p, ¿Cómo oculto sólo el texto que esta debajo del boton y no todos? En otras palabras, cuando se de clic en un boton se debe ocultar el texto que este debajo suyo y evitar que todos se oculten. (Aún soy novato en Jquery). Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solo requieres ocultar el texto, entonces debes cambiar tu variable s por algo como esto:

```
var s = $(this).parent().parent().find(".contenedor p");
```

pero si también quieres ocultar el cuadro gris que contiene el texto, entonces la respuesta de @Lobos es la indicada.

Comment: Tu respuesta era lo que espera que hiciera el boton. Gracias, problema resuelto.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){

$('button').on('click',function(){

var s = $(this) // botón al que se dio click
       .parent() // navegar hacia su padre '<section>'
       // en el padre buscar sus hermanos que tenga la clase .contenedor
       .siblings('.contenedor') 
       // elegir el primer hermano con esa clase
      .first();

if ($(this).text() === 'Ocultar'){
    $(this).text('Mostrar');
    s.fadeOut();    
} else {
    $(this).text('Ocultar');
    s.fadeIn();
}

});
  });
```

```css
.contenedor{
background: #EDEDED; height: 300px; width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<section>
<button>Ocultar</button>
</section>
<div class="contenedor">
    <p>tortuga</p>
</div>
    </div>
<br>

<div class="container">
 <section>
<button>Ocultar</button>
</section>  
<div class="contenedor">
    <p>gato</p>
</div>
    </div>
<br>

<div class="container">
<section>
<button>Ocultar</button>
</section>
<div class="contenedor">
    <p>loro</p>
</div>
    </div>
<br>
<div class="container">
<section>
<button>Ocultar</button>
</section>
<div class="contenedor">
    <p>pato</p>
</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola todo el problema se reduce a elegir un selector adecuado de modo que **apunte** al elemento **p** que deseas ocultar.
Como tanto el **button** como **p** están dentro de un mismo **div** mientras que los demás se encuentran en otros bloques, te debe funcionar `.closest('p')` El **p** más cercano.

```
// En tu script  
$('button').on('click',function(){
    // var s = $('.contenedor p'); // debe cambiar por
    var s = $( this ).closest('p');
    // no revisé el resto del código. A primera vista parece correcto.
```

referencia [jQuery closest selector](https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest-selector)